# How the AmE speakers call a building's apartment

Tags: word-choice

What do the AmE speakers call the apartment number 13 in a building which has e.g. 20 apartments when they are mentioning to their postal address:

**Apartment** / **unit** 13 - No 10 - Harvard street - Massachusetts - United states

> **1)** Apartment 13
>
> **2)** Unit 13

Comment: In countries like the US, Canada, the UK ...I think they have 12 and then direct 14! :)

Comment: Hi dear Maulik. :) 
thank you for being of help. You are always helpful my friend. :)
Just do they call e.g. direct 14 or something like that? :-?

Comment: I can only guess (non-native speaker)... direct... say.. *#13, Harvard Street...*

Comment: No No; You got me wrong. I am going to mention the number of the flat/apartment inside of a building which contains for example 20 apartments and I work in the apartment number 13. i need to know how Americans call it. A 'unit' or 'apartment' or what?

Comment: then, it's *number 13* or just *13*

Comment: @CarSmack thank you very much for the help, but please tell me about the word 'condo'. Is it possible to use it here; I mean e.g. "Condo 13 No 10 - Harvard street - Massachusetts - United states"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, we usually give an address like this:

10 Harvard Street
Apartment/Unit/Condo/Suite/Room 13
City Name, Massachusetts
zip code (if needed)

The street number and street name comes *first*. Then the unit number. However, many condos have their own unique street address.

You use that order whether giving someone your address or writing your address down on paper. If you are going to mail a letter, use the official two-letter abbreviation for the state (MA for Massachusetts).

As for whether it is okay to say condo, I don't know. First off, different parts of the USA refer to things differently. In some places an apartment is a single bedroom in a shared condo. In most places, an apartment is a rented home (consisting of a number of bedrooms, bathrooms, living room, dining room, kitchen, etc) in an apartment complex.

However, if you are talking about a specific unit (#13) in a building of 20 "apartments" (see, here I do not know whether you mean 20 rooms or 20 apartment homes), then say the appropriate word, then the number: Apartment #13, Unit #13, Condo #13. But in many condos they also just say Apartment Number and Unit Number.

*In an office bulding, we can say Suite 13.* We don't say Apartment 13 or Unit 13 for office building: these are used for places where people live. Unit can also refer to a storage unit, where one stores all the junk that they cannot fit in their house. :)

Comment: I suppose it's not absolutely needed, but most USPO personnel would **strongly** suggest you use a zip code.

Comment: We also often just say #.... as in "10 Harvard Street, #4"

Answer (score 4):

I'm not disputing CarSmack's answer; I'm simply offering a second opinion.

Those who deliver mail for the US Post Office are pretty smart about what they are doing. There are plenty of ways to address the mail, and all of them will arrive just fine.

My recommendation would probably be:

> 10 Harvard Street Apt 13
>   Boston MA  02134

However, for unit or apt numbers, you don't necessarily need to specify UNIT or APT. These will work, too:

> 10 Harvard Street #13
>   Boston MA  02134

or:

> 10 Harvard Street No 13
>   Boston MA  02134

Any carrier worth his salt will get those to the right address.

NOTES: In writing, there is normally a comma between the city and state names. The USPO prefers those not be used, so as to aid and not confuse character recognition software. The post office also recommends using ALL CAPS on packages and envelopes, but that is not required. [More here](http://pe.usps.com/businessmail101/addressing/deliveryAddress.htm).

As for how to say these verbally, you can either use the term that is common in your building (often *apartment*, but it could also be *suite, unit,* or the very generic *number*).

I would **say** the address in your example as follows:

> *I'm living at ten Harvard Street, apartment 13, Boston, Mass, 0-2-1-3-4"

In the U.S., when dealing with addresses, the first character of that zip code is often pronounced "oh", not "zero".

Comment: Well, some Americans pronounce the zero as "oh", in phone numbers as well as in addresses. I prefer to pronounce "0" as  "zero" and "O" as "oh". my zip is nine-zero-five-zero-five. So sue me. Or call my one-eight-oh-oh number.

Comment: @Brian - Nice catch. I've made an edit. I should have been more general; I didn't mean to claim that no zero in a zip code is ever pronounced "zero," only that "oh" is often used and is considered acceptable. (Also, for this particular zip code, I was remembering watching the television show _Zoom_ as a kid; they would [sing their zip code in a jingle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Q9v3tZ5IC4).)